# How send correctly mouse coordinates inside TImage component to Android Path.moveTo() and Path.lineTo() methods?

Tags: delphi, canvas, delphi-10.3-rio, timage, mouse-coordinates

I found a android code that your goal is simulates an L-shaped drag path: 200 pixels right, then 200 pixels down. These values was predefined on code, how this could be achieved using the mouse coordinates of a `TImage` component and your events ("mousedown", "mouseup" etc)? **PS:** I need this to implement in my remote access example (Delphi controller > Android client).

Here is the android code >

```
// Simulates an L-shaped drag path: 200 pixels right, then 200 pixels down.
Path path = new Path();
path.moveTo(200,200);
path.lineTo(400,200);

final GestureDescription.StrokeDescription sd = new GestureDescription.StrokeDescription(path, 0, 500, true);

// The starting point of the second path must match
// the ending point of the first path.
Path path2 = new Path();
path2.moveTo(400,200);
path2.lineTo(400,400);

final GestureDescription.StrokeDescription sd2 = sd.continueStroke(path2, 0, 500, false); // 0.5 second

HongBaoService.mService.dispatchGesture(new GestureDescription.Builder().addStroke(sd).build(), new AccessibilityService.GestureResultCallback(){

@Override
public void onCompleted(GestureDescription gestureDescription){
super.onCompleted(gestureDescription);
HongBaoService.mService.dispatchGesture(new GestureDescription.Builder().addStroke(sd2).build(),null,null);
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(GestureDescription gestureDescription){
super.onCancelled(gestureDescription);
}
},null);
```